# How to set Etag for a url in play framework?

Tags: http-headers, playframework-2.0, etag

I have already searched to set Etag in playframework. All I got are
1) https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Assets
2) https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaResponse

First option only works for Asset or files.
Second option does not work. I just added the three given in the example.

Comment: Adding some of your code would be advisable.

Answer (score 6):

Actually usage of Etag is described in Play's [doc for assets](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Assets#Etag-support) (that you linked as first) and also in [Wikipedia *Typical usage* section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag#Typical_usage).

At the beginning of the action you need to determine if requested resource has been changed since previous generation of the Etag, if yes, then you need to generate new content with new Etag, otherwise you only return the `304 NotModified` response.

Of course all depends on the kind of requested resource, anyway quite clean sample may be a database entity, with some ID and field with date/time of last modification:

```java
public static Result eTaggedFoo(Long id) {

    Foo foo = Foo.find.byId(id);
    if (foo == null) return notFound("Given Foo was not found");

    String eTag = DigestUtils.md5Hex(foo.id + foo.lastModification.toString());

    String ifNoneMatch = request().getHeader("If-None-Match");
    if (ifNoneMatch != null && ifNoneMatch.equals(eTag)) return status(304);

    response().setHeader(ETAG, eTag);
    return ok("Here you can see the " + foo.name + ", last modified: " + foo.lastModification.toString());

}
```

Comment: +1 This actually works and it's quite simple. Although I got a bit confused by the type asset you are returning (`String`). Anyway one question, why using `MD5` of `id` plus string representation of `date`? Why not just sum two `Long` and use that? I know `MD5` looks more professional but wouldn't `String eTag = String.valueOf((foo.id + foo.lastModification.getTime()))` be same bulletproof but much faster?

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25. e.g. `If-Modified-Since: Sat, 29 Oct 1994 19:43:31 GMT`